# Apple MBP 7,1 Color profile xcalib

Tags: kubuntu, macbook, apple

I have installed Kubuntu 64bit on my MBP 7,1. 
After installation I was going through following documentation (screen)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Maverick#Screen

I am confused about line
/usr/bin/xcalib "/etc/xcalib/**`<insert name of profile here>`**"

which profile to put at that place?

I am getting following output on command prompt

```
bharat@bharat-MacBookPro:~$ ls /etc/xcalib 
Color LCD-00000610-0000-9CC5-0000-000004273140.icc
EPSON PJ    -00004CA3-0000-A600-0000-000028E98001.icc
SyncMaster-00004C2D-0000-0117-4C45-31370B4074F5.icc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the Color LCD one as the EPSON one is for a printer and the SyncMaster one is likely an external monitor.